# Get GPS coordinates using Wifi or mobile network

Tags: android, location

i  have next problem, i need to get coordinates using internet, but when i connect with mobile internet (Edge) i get the same coordinates in whoole my flat, when i use WI Fi coordinates are different.
My code is :

```
public class FetchCordinates extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    ProgressDialog progDailog = null;

    public LocationManager mLocationManager;
    public VeggsterLocationListener mVeggsterLocationListener;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mVeggsterLocationListener = new VeggsterLocationListener();
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 10,
                mVeggsterLocationListener);

        progDailog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());


        progDailog.setTitle("Получение координат");
        progDailog
                .setMessage("Получение Вашего местоположения, ожидайте, это может занять несколько минут...");
        progDailog.setIndeterminate(true);


        progDailog.setCancelable(false);
        progDailog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Отмена",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        FetchCordinates.this.cancel(true);
                        mLocationManager
                                .removeUpdates(mVeggsterLocationListener);
                    }
                });
        progDailog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        Log.d("myLogs", "Cancelled by user!");
        progDailog.dismiss();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progDailog.dismiss();
        if (myLat == 0) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTitle("Ошибка получения координат")
                    .setMessage("Попробуйте позже...")
                    .setPositiveButton("Ок",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    // continue with delete
                                }
                            }).show();

        } else {

            pg = new Progress();
            pg.execute("");
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        long timeOfStartingThread = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (myLat == 0.0) {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeOfStartingThread > timeToGetGps_ms) {
                break;
            }
        }
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mVeggsterLocationListener);
        return null;
    }

    public class VeggsterLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            try {



                myLat = location.getLatitude();
                myLong = location.getLongitude();

                 Toast.makeText(
                 getActivity(),
                 " Координаты получены :" + myLat
                 + ", :" + myLong,
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.d("myLogs", "OnProviderDisabled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.d("myLogs", "onProviderEnabled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
            Log.d("myLogs", "onStatusChanged");

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The GPS is per default unfortunately not very reliable, but should be accurate down to 5-10 meters in outdoor environments; it's even worse indoors as you probably imagine. A lot of people have reported, that they are not even able to receive coordinates in indoor environments.

Unfortunately, the GPS accuracy furthermore depends on both the smartphone at hand and weather conditions, so there is really no specific way of determining the exact accuracy.

So my best guess is, that it is simply not possible to obtain better results than you currently receive.

Sorry (I guess)

Comment: Ok, i thing you are rigth.